# Problems with verifying .NET app that uses Gmail

Tags: c#, gmail, gmail-api

I've created an console app that reads my Gmail inbox one time in every hour, that app is deployed to Azure and is running as a WebJob.

Got an email from Google about not having Contest Screen. Google wants me to enter 'Application Homepage link', but there isn't any, since it is not a web site.

Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: Set one up - https://pages.github.com/ ?

Comment: Thanks the plan if the Azure WebJob page doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If your app is only for your organization or G Suite domain, you can mark it as internal-only in the OAuth consent screen configuration:
>
> 1. Go to the GCP Console OAuth consent screen page.
> 2. Click the Project selector drop-down at the top of the page.
> 3. On the Select from dialog that appears, select your project.
> 4. Under Application type, select Internal, and then click Save.

If the above does not apply to you then.
Unfortunately the only way to solve it is to put up a page that they ask for.   I recommend finding some kind of free hosting page.   Azure and Google both offer free hosting of web sties i believe.  As mentioned pages.github.com could also be an option.

- [Unverified apps](https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/7454865?hl=en)
- [OAuth Application Verification FAQ](https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/9110914?hl=en)

Comment: Hi @DalmTo, there is no option for Application Type to be Internal, it is set to Other, and cannot be changed. I've sent them URL to the Azure WebJob, and now I way to there verification. But I agree with your idea, thanks for the help :)

Comment: If internal isnt an option then i will contact the team and have the documentation corrected.